# How is working with multiple angular versions?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

My current angular version is 8.2.14. I was installed it globally before `npm install -g @angular/cli`. And angular versions of my projects are same.

So now angular version 9 is released. So, if I install it globally,

1. Does my projects work?
2. Should I convert all projects to angular 9?

Or will all projects compile own angular version in package.json?

Comment: Your project use the version you provided in the `package.json` file. If the project use the version 1 and you have, globally, the version 2, it will anyway use the version 1. If you have specified the version 2 and globally you have the version 1 it will give you an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can progressively update any project you will be putting your hand on in the future, by removing the -g (global) parameter.
Follow the Angular update guide to update the single project: https://update.angular.io/#8.2:9.0l2

1. Projects you don't touch will use the version of their local `package.json`.
2. Not necessarily. Projects can all remain with the old version, in their personal `package.json`. The projects where you go to hand may want to update them.

Comment: What means "Projects you don't touch"?

Comment: Projects you don't touch = Projects you don't change.
Those projects that you will no longer modify can remain with an old version of Angular. In my case I have several Angular projects and I could never start updating them all.